# How to return middle records in rails db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

To get the last 10 records in my rails db, I use:

```
pictures = Picture.last(10)
```

How do I get the 10 before these?

```
pictures = Picture.last(20)
```

returns 20 results, not just the records from 11-20.

Comment: There *is* no "10 after that". The last ten records are the **last** ten records.

Comment: Sorry, the 10 before the last 10.

Comment: Use `limit` and `offset`.

Comment: Do you want to write an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: check my post may be your answer ...thanks

Comment: hmmm... I thought you need LAST 10 BEFORE last 10 records, 'cuz combination of limit(n) and offset(k) gives you FIRST n records after k records

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want records between 11 and 20 you could do

`Picture.limit(10).offset(11)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```
Picture.order('id DESC').limit(10).offset(11)
```

or you could do it based on `created_at`

```
Picture.order('created_at DESC').limit(10).offset(11)
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple 
`Order.offset(10).last(10)`